# extracting a file name from file path in c++

Tags: c++, indexing, stdstring

I have a string storing path of a file and I'm doing some string processing, indexing of a `std::string` object, but output string is strange, code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\QBFdata.txt";
    string temp = "";
    for(int  i = x.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(x[i] == '\\')
            break;
        else
            temp.append(&x[i]);
    }
 cout << temp << "\n";
}
```

but output is strange apparently it append the contents of `temp` again to it.

> txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txtBFdata.txtQBFdata.txt

Please don't suggest any alternatives to this because I already have a solution

```
int main()
{
    string x = "C:\\Users\\NK\\Desktop\\QBFdata.txt";
    int pos = x.find_last_of('\\');
    string temp = x.substr(pos + 1);
    cout << temp;
}
```

It works fine.

I want to know what is the problem in the first code.

Thanks.

I'm using codeblocks 16.01

Comment: Very easy using [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) if you have it available, or [`std::experimental::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path). Or [Boost filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) and its [`path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) class.

Comment: You are calling the overload of [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) that accepts a null-terminated `const char*` - read up how that works

Comment: _"Please don't suggest any alternatives to this because I already have a solution"_ Pro Tip: You can self answer your questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, the problem is that you are using the wrong overload of `std::string::append()`, so you are appending whole substrings, not individual characters, on each loop iteration.

To append a single character at a time, use one of these instead:

```
temp.append(&x[i], 1);
```

```
temp.push_back(x[i]);
```

```
temp += x[i];
```

However since you are looping backwards, you need to **prepend** each character in the FRONT of the string instead of **append** to the BACK:

```
temp.insert(0, &x[i], 1);
```

```
temp = x[i] + temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, goes like this:

Your original code starts from the back of the string first, so the first time your code runs the `if(x[i] == '\\')` line, it is looking at `x[34]`.

`x[34]` is the `"t"` at the end of your path.

Next your code appends that to the as yet empty temp string.

Next time it iterates it looks at the `x[33]`.

`x[33]` is the reference to the `'x'` character. Now if you were only appending once character at a time all would be well (except your string would be backwards). However the append function of a string appends another string, so I think what's happening (more experienced programmers please correct me if I'm wrong), the compiler I think is doing an implicit conversion from a `char*` (which is what a C style string is if it ends in a null) to a `std::string` object and appending that string.

This means that it's appending the c-string beginning at the `'x'` character so this time it appends the `"xt"` onto the back of the t from above.

Next iteration references a c-string beginning at x[32] so it appends `"txt"`
Next iteration references a c-string beginning at x[31] so it appends `".txt"`
Next iteration references a c-string beginning at x[30] so it appends `"a.txt"`
then `"ta.txt"` and so on...

total it gives you the following strings all appended in the following order:

```
"t" + "xt" + "txt" + ".txt" + "a.txt" + "ta.txt" + "ata.txt" + "data.txt" + "Fdata.txt" + "BFdata.txt" + "QBFdata.txt"
```

rendering your final string as: `"txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txtBFdata.txtQBFdata.txt"`

Hope this helps.

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this output is because when you do:

```
temp.append(&x[i]);
```

It **doesn't append a single letter**,
but rather the **entire suffix of the string**, from the index `i`.
Here is the output of your code when I printed temp in each iteration

```
temp.append(&x[i]);
cout << temp << "\n";
```

The output shows you first append the single letter t, then xt, then txt, etc.

```
t
txt
txttxt
txttxt.txt
txttxt.txta.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txtBFdata.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txtBFdata.txtQBFdata.txt
txttxt.txta.txtta.txtata.txtdata.txtFdata.txtBFdata.txtQBFdata.txt
```